# Apache authentication, security exceptions and safari

Tags: apache, authentication, safari

I have apache authentication set up on a site, it works fine in firefox and chrome, you type in the username/pass once and then you can happily visit any page on the site. Unfortunately this is not the behavior in safari. Every time you go to another page, you must re-enter your credentials.

Is there some way I can look at the security exceptions for safari and set it to always trust the certificate or find some other setting to not ask for authentication on each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem of Safari on Windows.

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/safari-http-auth/

Considering the fact that Basic authentication is a historical relic these days, you can stop using it and switch to a form based authentication instead.

Or there are Apache modules which allows you to set up cookies on client side just by using Basic authentication

I guess you can also check this question here https://serverfault.com/questions/62570/cookie-authentication-in-apache which shows a method  to achieve this using URL rewriting.